# Multisite and users being listed on network administration dashboard and not main site dashboard

Tags: multisite, user-roles

I have a main site that is a buddypress site.  I later converted main site to a multisite configuration.  Now, when people sign up they are put on my network administration dashboard as a user and not my main site as users and they don't have roles.  What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install related plugins for users ? Because there are certain plugins that when people register then they come across all websites (e.g http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-user-management/)